# Converting entity to JSON

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

I am quite new to Drupal and Drupal 8.

I have created a custom module that creates a custom content type. I am attempting to extract those entities and display them as JSON or XML.

I have read through the [Entities Api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!entity.api.php/group/entity_api/8) on loading, querying, and rendering entities but I am struggling to find view_mode_name types :

```
$build = $view_builder->view($entity, 'view_mode_name', $language->getId());
```

Would I be able to do something like :

```
$build = $view_builder->view($entity, 'xml', $language->getId());
```

or does this only produce a 'render array' ? If this is the case then should I be looking at the [Serializer Api](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/serialization#get-serializer) ? If so would anyone be able to guide me in the right direction on using this ?

Here is my code so far :

```
public function display() {
// use the debug component
Debug::enable();

// get node -> testimonial content types
$entity_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'testimonial')
->execute(); // fetch

$node_storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');

$data = $node_storage->loadMultiple($entity_ids);

$view_builder = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node');

// render multiple 
return $view_builder->viewMultiple($data, 'xml');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View builders only display HTML/render arrays.

Look into the serialization/rest/hal modules if you want to extract the data of your entity, as you guessed already.

Note that REST in core only supports content entities at the moment, but I assume you have one of those.

Also, I'd recommend hal+json serialization, provided by the hal.module instead of the raw json seralization, as that can't deal with things like references properly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Berdir. My entity is a content one so I should be good with the hal.module. Time to read up on the Symfony service container..